# JavaFX Making Copies of Same Animation

Tags: java, javafx

I am attempting to expand on a previous assignment. It was to draw a fan and have a slider to control the play speed, along with having buttons to play, pause, and reverse the fans. Here is my code for that assignment:

```
public class FanWithControls extends Application {
    @Override // Override the start method in the Application class
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    FanPane fan = new FanPane();
    StackPane spane = new StackPane();
    spane.getChildren().addAll(fan);
    HBox hBox = new HBox(5);
    Button btPause = new Button("Pause");
    Button btResume = new Button("Resume");
    Button btReverse = new Button("Reverse");
    hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    hBox.getChildren().addAll(btPause, btResume, btReverse); 
    Slider slider = new Slider(0,10, 3);
    slider.setShowTickLabels(true);
    slider.setShowTickMarks(true);

    BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
    pane.setCenter(spane);
    pane.setTop(hBox);
    pane.setBottom(slider);

    // Create a scene and place it in the stage
    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 300, 400);
    primaryStage.setTitle("FanWithControls"); // Set the stage title
    primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage
    primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage

    Timeline animation = new Timeline(
                                      new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(50), e ->      fan.move()));
    animation.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    animation.play(); // Start animation

    scene.widthProperty().addListener(e -> fan.setW(fan.getWidth()));
    scene.heightProperty().addListener(e -> fan.setH(fan.getHeight()));

    btPause.setOnAction(e -> animation.pause());
    btResume.setOnAction(e -> animation.play());
    btReverse.setOnAction(e -> fan.reverse());

    slider.valueProperty().addListener(ov -> animation.setRate(slider.getValue()));

}

/**
 * The main method is only needed for the IDE with limited
 * JavaFX support. Not needed for running from the command line.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
class FanPane extends Pane {
private double w = 200;
private double h = 200;
private double radius = Math.min(w, h) * 0.45;
private Arc arc[] = new Arc[4];
private double startAngle = 30;
private Circle circle = new Circle(w / 2, h / 2, radius);


public FanPane() {
    circle.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
    circle.setFill(Color.WHITE);
    circle.setStrokeWidth(4);
    getChildren().add(circle);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        arc[i] = new Arc(w / 2, h / 2, radius * 0.9, radius * 0.9,    startAngle + i * 90, 35);
        arc[i].setFill(Color.RED); // Set fill color
        arc[i].setType(ArcType.ROUND);
        getChildren().addAll(arc[i]);
    }
}

private double increment = 5;

public void reverse() {
    increment = -increment;
}

public void move() {
    setStartAngle(startAngle + increment);
}

public void setStartAngle(double angle) {
    startAngle = angle;
    setValues();
}

public void setValues() {
    radius = Math.min(w, h) * 0.45;
    circle.setRadius(radius);
    circle.setCenterX(w / 2);
    circle.setCenterY(h / 2);


    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        arc[i].setRadiusX(radius * 0.9);
        arc[i].setRadiusY(radius * 0.9);
        arc[i].setCenterX(w / 2);
        arc[i].setCenterY(h / 2);
        arc[i].setStartAngle(startAngle + i * 90);
    }
}

public void setW(double w) {
    this.w = w;
    setValues();
}

public void setH(double h) {
    this.h = h;
    setValues();
}

public double getCenterX() {
  return circle.getCenterX();
}

public double getCenterY() {
  return circle.getCenterY();
}

public double getRadius() {
  return circle.getRadius();
}
}
```

I was wondering if anyone could help me with this. I am having an extremely hard time getting this to work. Ive tried making an hbox that contains multiple fanpanes but they shrink in size and dont grow when I resize the box.

Basically I am trying to make it so you can have a slider that will allow you to have up to 5 fanpanes. Increasing it will add more fanpanes, decreasing it will take them away, etc.

Any tips or help would be greatly appreciated thank you!

Comment: You can use `FlowPane` instead of `StackPane`, and add and remove fanpanes based on the slider value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaFX Homework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34006885/javafx-homework)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `FlowPane` instead of `StackPane` and declare the Animation inside `FanPane` class. Here's the code

```
public class FanWithControls extends Application {

    @Override // Override the start method in the Application class
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        FanPane fan = new FanPane();
        FlowPane spane = new FlowPane();
        spane.getChildren().addAll(fan);
        HBox hBox = new HBox(5);
        Button btPause = new Button("Pause");
        Button btResume = new Button("Resume");
        Button btReverse = new Button("Reverse");
        hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        hBox.getChildren().addAll(btPause, btResume, btReverse);
        Slider slider = new Slider(0, 10, 3);
        slider.setShowTickLabels(true);
        slider.setShowTickMarks(true);

        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        pane.setCenter(spane);
        pane.setTop(hBox);
        pane.setBottom(slider);

        // Create a scene and place it in the stage
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 300, 400);
        primaryStage.setTitle("FanWithControls"); // Set the stage title
        primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage
        primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage

        fan.setAnimation(fan);
        Timeline animation = fan.getAnimation();

        scene.widthProperty().addListener(e -> fan.setW(fan.getWidth()));
        scene.heightProperty().addListener(e -> fan.setH(fan.getHeight()));

        btPause.setOnAction((e) -> {
            for (Node fans : spane.getChildren()) {
                FanPane fanpane = (FanPane) fans;
                fanpane.getAnimation().pause();
            }
//            animation.pause();
        });
        btResume.setOnAction((e) -> {
            for (Node fans : spane.getChildren()) {
                FanPane fanpane = (FanPane) fans;
                fanpane.getAnimation().play();
            }
//            animation.play();
        });
        btReverse.setOnAction((e) -> {
            for (Node fans : spane.getChildren()) {
                FanPane fanpane = (FanPane) fans;
                fanpane.reverse();
            }
//            fan.reverse();
        });

        slider.valueProperty().addListener((ov) -> {
//            animation.setRate(slider.getValue());
            for (Node fans : spane.getChildren()) {
                FanPane fanpane = (FanPane) fans;
                fanpane.getAnimation().setRate(slider.getValue());
            }
            if (spane.getChildren().size() < (int) slider.getValue()) {
                for (int i = spane.getChildren().size(); i < (int) slider.getValue(); i++) {
                    FanPane fanPane = new FanPane();
                    spane.getChildren().add(fanPane);
                    fanPane.setAnimation(fanPane);
                    fanPane.getAnimation().setRate(slider.getValue());
                }
            } else if (spane.getChildren().size() > (int) slider.getValue()) {
                for (int i = (int) slider.getValue(); i < spane.getChildren().size(); i++) {
                    spane.getChildren().remove(spane.getChildren().size() - 1);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * The main method is only needed for the IDE with limited JavaFX support.
     * Not needed for running from the command line.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    class FanPane extends Pane {

        private double w = 200;
        private double h = 200;
        private double radius = Math.min(w, h) * 0.45;
        private Arc arc[] = new Arc[4];
        private double startAngle = 30;
        private Circle circle = new Circle(w / 2, h / 2, radius);
        private Timeline animation;

        public FanPane() {
            circle.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
            circle.setFill(Color.WHITE);
            circle.setStrokeWidth(4);
            getChildren().add(circle);

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                arc[i] = new Arc(w / 2, h / 2, radius * 0.9, radius * 0.9, startAngle + i * 90, 35);
                arc[i].setFill(Color.RED); // Set fill color
                arc[i].setType(ArcType.ROUND);
                getChildren().addAll(arc[i]);
            }

        }

        public Timeline getAnimation() {
            return animation;
        }

        public void setAnimation(FanPane fan) {
            this.animation = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(50), e -> fan.move()));
            animation.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
            animation.play();
        }

        private double increment = 5;

        public void reverse() {
            increment = -increment;
        }

        public void move() {
            setStartAngle(startAngle + increment);
        }

        public void setStartAngle(double angle) {
            startAngle = angle;
            setValues();
        }

        public void setValues() {
            radius = Math.min(w, h) * 0.45;
            circle.setRadius(radius);
            circle.setCenterX(w / 2);
            circle.setCenterY(h / 2);

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                arc[i].setRadiusX(radius * 0.9);
                arc[i].setRadiusY(radius * 0.9);
                arc[i].setCenterX(w / 2);
                arc[i].setCenterY(h / 2);
                arc[i].setStartAngle(startAngle + i * 90);
            }
        }

        public void setW(double w) {
            this.w = w;
            setValues();
        }

        public void setH(double h) {
            this.h = h;
            setValues();
        }

        public double getCenterX() {
            return circle.getCenterX();
        }

        public double getCenterY() {
            return circle.getCenterY();
        }

        public double getRadius() {
            return circle.getRadius();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this is great! So far Ive been able to change the code to where The user can add up to 5 fanpanes, each coming with their own play/pause/resume buttons. They also each have an individual slider to change the speed of the fans.

I wanted to add a slider that would change the number of "blades" in each of the fan pane. This one is currently set to 4, and Im having an issue trying to create a slider so they can have anywhere from 0 to 10 blades, any ideas? Thanks again! I was able to get so much further with this tip!

Comment: To change no. of blades you need to work in the `FanPane` class. Make the calculation dynamic rather than constant, use getter setter to pass updated values.

Comment: Could you explain getter setter to me? I tried making an int value z, with simpleintegerproperty binded to the slider2 value. I then tried to set the z value to that, but it wasnt creating them properly. It would leave non moving blades on the screen and wouldnt create them properly inside the circle. 

Thanks again for the reply! I knew I was on the right track before but I didnt quite get it solved. Any tips on why my fans arent lining up inside their circles properly?