# JavaFX Homework

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Looking to finish out this homework. I have a program that will show up to 5 "FanPanes" that will have a fan spinning. You can use a slider to control the speed of the fans, and use buttons to stop, play, and reverse the directions of the fans.

I am having issues with figuring out how make my slider ("slider2" is what I want to use for it from the class FanPane) update the number of blades the fan shows. I want to be able to have anywhere from 1 blade shown to 10 blades.

Also, I am having issues with getting my fans lined up properly. I had it correct before and now that I've added these new sliders my blades don't line up properly inside my circles.

Here is my code:

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Arc;
import javafx.scene.shape.ArcType;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.text.*;

public class FanWithControls extends Application {

    @Override // Override the start method in the Application class
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        FanPane fan = new FanPane();
        FlowPane spane = new FlowPane(5, 5);
        spane.getChildren().addAll(fan);
        HBox hBox = new HBox(5);
        GridPane botPane = new GridPane();
        Label numFans = new Label("Num Fans:      ");
        Label blades = new Label("       Blades:    ");
        Label total = new Label("Control All Fans:         ");
        Button btPause = new Button("Pause");
        Button btResume = new Button("Resume");
        Button btReverse = new Button("Reverse");
        hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        hBox.getChildren().addAll(btPause, btResume, btReverse);
        Slider slider = new Slider(0, 5, 0);
        Slider bSlider = new Slider(0, 10,0);
        slider.setShowTickLabels(true);
        slider.setShowTickMarks(true);
        bSlider.setShowTickLabels(true);
        bSlider.setShowTickMarks(true);

        botPane.getChildren().addAll(numFans, slider, blades, bSlider, total);
        botPane.setConstraints(total, 0, 0);
        botPane.setConstraints(numFans, 3, 0);
        botPane.setConstraints(slider, 4, 0);
        botPane.setConstraints(blades, 6, 0);
        botPane.setConstraints(bSlider, 7, 0);


        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        pane.setPadding(new Insets(10, 30, 12, 12));
        pane.setCenter(spane);
        pane.setTop(hBox);
        pane.setBottom(botPane);

        // Create a scene and place it in the stage
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 1200, 400);
        primaryStage.setTitle("FanWithControls"); // Set the stage title
        primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage
        primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage

        fan.setAnimation(fan);
        Timeline animation = fan.getAnimation();

        //scene.widthProperty().addListener(e -> fan.setW(fan.getWidth()));
        //scene.heightProperty().addListener(e -> fan.setH(fan.getHeight()));
        spane.setHgap(5);

        btPause.setOnAction((e) -> {
            for (Node fans : spane.getChildren()) {
                FanPane fanpane = (FanPane) fans;
                fanpane.getAnimation().pause();
            }
//            animation.pause();
        });
        btResume.setOnAction((e) -> {
            for (Node fans : spane.getChildren()) {
                FanPane fanpane = (FanPane) fans;
                fanpane.getAnimation().play();
            }
//            animation.play();
        });
        btReverse.setOnAction((e) -> {
            for (Node fans : spane.getChildren()) {
                FanPane fanpane = (FanPane) fans;
                fanpane.reverse();
            }
//            fan.reverse();
        });

        slider.valueProperty().addListener((ov) -> {
//            animation.setRate(slider.getValue());

            if (spane.getChildren().size() < (int) slider.getValue()) {
                for (int i = spane.getChildren().size(); i < (int) slider.getValue(); i++) {
                    FanPane fanPane = new FanPane();
                    spane.getChildren().add(fanPane);
                    fanPane.setAnimation(fanPane);
                    fanPane.rate();
                }
            } else if (spane.getChildren().size() > (int) slider.getValue()) {
                for (int i = (int) slider.getValue(); i < spane.getChildren().size(); i++) {
                    spane.getChildren().remove(spane.getChildren().size() - 1);
                }
            }
        });

    }


    /**
     * The main method is only needed for the IDE with limited JavaFX support.
     * Not needed for running from the command line.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    class FanPane extends Pane {

        private double w = 200;
        private double h = 200;
        private double radius = Math.min(w, h) * 0.45;
        private Arc arc[] = new Arc[4];
        private double startAngle = 30;
        private Circle circle = new Circle(w / 2, h / 2, radius);
        private Timeline animation;
        private Slider slider1 = new Slider(0, 15, 0);
        private Slider slider2 = new Slider(0, 10, 0);
        private BorderPane bpane = new BorderPane();
        private Button pauseBt = new Button("Pause");
        private Button resumeBt = new Button("Resume");
        private Button reverseBt = new Button("Reverse");
        private HBox btBox = new HBox(5);
        private Label blank = new Label("       ");
        private Label speed = new Label("Fan Speed: ");
        private Label numBlades = new Label("Num Blades: ");
        private VBox topBox = new VBox();
        private VBox midBox = new VBox();
        private GridPane gpane = new GridPane();

        public FanPane() {
            circle.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
            circle.setFill(Color.WHITE);
            circle.setStrokeWidth(4);
            getChildren().add(bpane);

            slider1.setShowTickLabels(true);
            slider1.setShowTickMarks(true);
            slider1.setMajorTickUnit(5);
            slider1.setMinorTickCount(0);
            slider1.setBlockIncrement(1);
            slider2.setShowTickLabels(true);
            slider2.setShowTickMarks(true);
            slider2.setMajorTickUnit(5);
            slider2.setMinorTickCount(0);
            slider2.setBlockIncrement(1);

            gpane.setConstraints(speed, 0, 0);
            gpane.setConstraints(slider1, 1, 0);
            gpane.setConstraints(numBlades, 0, 1);
            gpane.setConstraints(slider2, 1, 1);
            gpane.getChildren().addAll(speed, slider1, numBlades, slider2);

            btBox.getChildren().addAll(pauseBt,resumeBt,reverseBt);
            topBox.getChildren().addAll(blank, btBox);


            bpane.setCenter(circle);
            bpane.setTop(topBox);
            bpane.setBottom(gpane);
            bpane.setAlignment(topBox, Pos.CENTER);

            pauseBt.setOnAction(e -> animation.pause());
            resumeBt.setOnAction(e -> animation.play());
            reverseBt.setOnAction(e -> this.reverse());

            bpane.widthProperty().addListener(e -> this.setW(this.getWidth()));
            bpane.heightProperty().addListener(e -> this.setH(this.getHeight()));

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                arc[i] = new Arc(w / 2, h / 2, radius * 0.9, radius * 0.9, startAngle + i * 90, 35);
                arc[i].setFill(Color.RED); // Set fill color
                arc[i].setType(ArcType.ROUND);
                getChildren().addAll(arc[i]);
            }

        }

        public Timeline getAnimation() {
            return animation;
        }

        public void setAnimation(FanPane fan) {
            this.animation = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(50), e -> fan.move()));
            animation.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
            animation.play();
        }

        private double increment = 5;

        public void reverse() {
            increment = -increment;
        }

        public void rate() {
          slider1.valueProperty().addListener(ov -> animation.setRate(slider1.getValue()));
        }

        public void move() {
            setStartAngle(startAngle + increment);
        }

        public void setStartAngle(double angle) {
            startAngle = angle;
            setValues();
        }

        public void setValues() {
            radius = Math.min(w, h) * 0.45;
            circle.setRadius(radius);
            circle.setCenterX(w / 2);
            circle.setCenterY(h / 2);

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                arc[i].setRadiusX(radius * 0.9);
                arc[i].setRadiusY(radius * 0.9);
                arc[i].setCenterX(w / 2);
                arc[i].setCenterY(h / 2);
                arc[i].setStartAngle(startAngle + i * 90);
            }
        }

        public void setW(double w) {
            this.w = w;
            setValues();
        }

        public void setH(double h) {
            this.h = h;
            setValues();
        }

        public double getCenterX() {
            return circle.getCenterX();
        }

        public double getCenterY() {
            return circle.getCenterY();
        }

        public double getRadius() {
            return circle.getRadius();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: How is this different from your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33989669/javafx-making-copies-of-same-animation)?

Comment: I marked my old question answered, I didnt see it anymore in my profile so I made another one. 

After I implemented the help from my last question, I started to add more things to my program. After I added individual sliders for individual fan speeds, my fan blades arent lining up properly anymore. 

Also, I am trying to figure out how to add a slider to change the number of blades inside the fan. I tried to add a slider that would change the integer in my for loop and array would work, but it definitely does not.

Comment: You need to understand what is done to make a 4 blade fanpane. Make those calculations generic to make n blade fanpane.

Comment: Your fans are not in the circle because you are adding the `arc` that is making your fan directly into the 'pane'` but you are adding your 'circle' int the 'borderPane' which is then added to the 'pane'.. Try adding both circle and arcs in a new `Pane` and then put that `pane` in the `borderpane`

Comment: I see now thank you so much! My fans are lined up properly again!

Answer (score -1):

To increase no. of blades dynamically, you need to change no. of arcs you are making, its length and angle difference.
Change your constructor of `FanPane` according to below code.

```
public FanPane(int blade) {
            circle.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
            circle.setFill(Color.WHITE);
            circle.setStrokeWidth(4);
            getChildren().add(bpane);

            slider1.setShowTickLabels(true);
            slider1.setShowTickMarks(true);
            slider1.setMajorTickUnit(5);
            slider1.setMinorTickCount(0);
            slider1.setBlockIncrement(1);
            slider2.setShowTickLabels(true);
            slider2.setShowTickMarks(true);
            slider2.setMajorTickUnit(5);
            slider2.setMinorTickCount(0);
            slider2.setBlockIncrement(1);

            gpane.setConstraints(speed, 0, 0);
            gpane.setConstraints(slider1, 1, 0);
            gpane.setConstraints(numBlades, 0, 1);
            gpane.setConstraints(slider2, 1, 1);
            gpane.getChildren().addAll(speed, slider1, numBlades, slider2);

            btBox.getChildren().addAll(pauseBt, resumeBt, reverseBt);
            topBox.getChildren().addAll(blank, btBox);

            Pane pane = new Pane(circle);
            bpane.setCenter(pane);
            bpane.setTop(topBox);
            bpane.setBottom(gpane);
//            bpane.setAlignment(topBox, Pos.CENTER);

            pauseBt.setOnAction(e -> animation.pause());
            resumeBt.setOnAction(e -> animation.play());
            reverseBt.setOnAction(e -> this.reverse());

//            bpane.widthProperty().addListener(e -> this.setW(this.getWidth()));
//            bpane.heightProperty().addListener(e -> this.setH(this.getHeight()));
            try {
            arc = new Arc[blade];
            int angleDiff = 360 / blade;
            for (int i = 0; i < blade; i++) {
                arc[i] = new Arc(w / 2, h / 2, radius * 0.9, radius * 0.9, startAngle + i * angleDiff, 180 / blade);
                arc[i].setFill(Color.RED); // Set fill color
                arc[i].setType(ArcType.ROUND);
                pane.getChildren().addAll(arc[i]);

            }
            } catch (ArithmeticException ex) {
                blade = 2;
                arc = new Arc[blade];
                int angleDiff = 360 / blade;
                for (int i = 0; i < blade; i++) {
                    arc[i] = new Arc(w / 2, h / 2, radius * 0.9, radius * 0.9, startAngle + i * angleDiff, 180 / blade);
                    arc[i].setFill(Color.RED); // Set fill color
                    arc[i].setType(ArcType.ROUND);
                    pane.getChildren().addAll(arc[i]);

                }
            }
        }
```